# The color changes depending on the truth of the falsity in the loop {% for%}. Django, Python, bootstrap

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple template that displays all the elements in my class. 
I would like the 'badge' color to change depending on whether the field 'free_or_no = models.BooleanField (default = None)' is checked or unchecked. 
However, the colors of all fields are changed at the same time, not the selected ones, in which the value is different. How can I solve this problem? any help will be appreciated.

```
{% for time in daytime %}

{% if daytime.free_or_no == True %}
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-pill badge-success text-uppercase">{{ time.name}}</span>
{% else %}
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-pill badge-danger text-uppercase">{{ time.name }}</span>
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the variable "daytime" to use it, the iterative cycle uses "time" for each item in the list.

```
{% for time in daytime %}

    {% if time.free_or_no == True %}
        <span class="badge badge-lg badge-pill badge-success text-uppercase">{{time.name}}</span>
    {% else %}
        <span class="badge badge-lg badge-pill badge-danger text-uppercase">{{ time.name }}</span>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```